# Infinite loop in program? no output returning in program?

Tags: c++

I have some working code. It does not work the way I wanted it to though. When I run the program I get no output what so ever. I did some debugging and I found some infinite loops. 
About the program I am doing: I am doing a infix to postfix program. I am using sstream, getting input from user as such and using peek and get to check for the next character.

The Function header where I am having problems is:`string infixconvert (istream& input)`

Were I think I have identified a infinite loop are:

```
     if (isspace(ch))
     {
         ch = input.get();
         ch = input.peek();
         continue;
     }
```

and here:

```
     if (isdigit(ch))
     {
         ch = (int)ch;
         postfixstack.push_back(ch);
         ch = input.peek();
         continue;
     }
```

when I did my own debugging, theses spots had infinite loops, I am not sure if infinite loops are the problem for no output. If anyone could run this code (The full program) in their compiler and see whats the error, I be most grateful. I need a new pair of eyes to look at this.

Here is the full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// This function converts a vector<int> to string.
string convertInt(vector<int> vec)
{
stringstream ss;//create a stringstream
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    ss  << " " << vec[i];//add number to the stream
}
return ss.str();//return a string with the contents of the stream
  }

 string infixconvert (istream& input)
 {
 // Have two Stacks made fro vectors one tempstack one, postfix
 vector<int> tempstack;
 vector<int> postfixstack; 
 // used to read in characters
 char ch;
 // Used to read in numbers, although, not used yet.
 int num = 0;
 ch = input.peek();
 // While not End of file
 while (ch != EOF)
 {
     // If white space skip it and continue
     if (isspace(ch))
     {
         ch = input.get();
         ch = input.peek();
         continue;
     }

     if (isdigit(ch))
     {
         // If ch is a digit, push it on to the postfix stack
         ch = (int)ch;
         postfixstack.push_back(ch);
         ch = input.peek();
         continue;
     }

     if (ch == '(' || ch == ')')
     {
         // if a open or closed paraenthiesis push on to tempstack
         // and pop it off
         tempstack.push_back(ch);
         tempstack.pop_back();
         ch = input.peek();
         continue;
     }

     // If operator, push on to tempstack
     if ( ch == '-' || ch == '+' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '%')
     {
         ch = (int)ch;
         tempstack.push_back(ch);
         ch = input.peek();

         // Check stack postfix, to see if operator needs to be pushed on
         // if there are two digits next by each other in postfix stack
         // push on to postfix stack, else continue loop.
         for (unsigned int n = 0; n < postfixstack.size(); n++)
         {
        for (unsigned int i = 1; i < postfixstack.size(); i++)
             {
                 if (isdigit(n) && isdigit(i) ||     postfixstack.size() <= 1)
                 {
                     postfixstack.push_back(ch);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     continue;
                 }
             }
             continue;
         }
     }

 }
 // convert to string
 return convertInt(postfixstack);
}

 int main()
 {
 string input;
 cout << "Enter a infix  expression to convert to postfix, "
     << " \nor a blank line to exit the program : ";
 getline(cin,input);
 while(input.size() != 0)
 {
     istringstream inputexpr(input);
     cout << "The postfix equivalent is "
          << infixconvert(inputexpr) << endl;
     cout << "Enter a infix expression to evaluate: ";
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you step through the infinite loop code and check why its stuck?

Comment: I tired to with the debugger, but it won't go through it. I am using visual studio 2008. So i been Debuggin with cout statements. I know that when it gets in the while statement it just infinite loops.

Comment: Okay I think the infinite loop starts at: 'while (ch != EOF)' I did some debugging points and found out that I cannot step through after that point.

Comment: In `while (ch != EOF)` loop, if `ch` does not meet any of your `if` condition, then you don't read the next character in the `input` sequence and stuck in the loop?

Comment: I think that could be the problem

Comment: `ch = input.peek();` This does not advance the read position.

Comment: `while(input.size() != 0)` input is not updated.

Comment: huh... okay I'll change that out with something else.